# INDIRECT If Statments keeps giving #REF

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to change an if statement to an indirect one as the current one that works keeps changing from C27 to #REF! when I delete Row 27 in the Tracker sheet.

```
  =IF('Tracker Sheet'!C27="","",'Tracker Sheet'!C27)
```

This is the old if statement that works

```
  =IF(INDIRECT('Tracker Sheet'!C27)="","",INDIRECT('Tracker Sheet'!C27))
```

This is the if statement that I try to convert but gives me #REF!

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use index:

```
=IF(INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!C:C,27)="","",INDEX('Tracker Sheet'!C:C,27))
```

As long as you use the cell address directly when it is deleted it will return `#REF` as you are deleting the reference.

This will always look at what is the current 27th row in column C.